# Speed up shapely buffer

Tags: python, performance, graphics

I was asked to move the code here.

I have different [`shapely.LineStrings`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#linestrings) like so:
[image]

which I then [`buffer`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#object.buffer) to create a polygon like so:
[image]

I've played around a bit and found that buffering each line segment is **slightly** faster than [`unary_union`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shapely.ops.cascaded_union)-ing all the linestrings and then buffering the whole thing together. However I do need the total area of the buffered lines as a shapely polygon as I am using it for intersection detection later. So I end up having to [`unary_union`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shapely.ops.cascaded_union) the buffered polygons to get the overall polygon and this is taking some time (not for this particular example but for other examples with more green lines).

So is there a faster way to get the buffered polygon that I am unaware of?

Here is a reproducible example:

```
import numpy as np
from shapely.geometry import MultiLineString, LineString, Polygon
from shapely import ops, affinity
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import atan2, degrees
from descartes.patch import PolygonPatch

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Coords = np.array([
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 'N', 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 'BRANCH', 'N', 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 'BRANCH', 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [-0.85, -0.51, 0, 'BRANCH', 'Y', 45, 0],
        [-0.85, -0.51, 0, 'NODE', 'Y', 45, 0],
        [-1.71, -1.03, 0, 0, 'Y', 45, 0],
        [-1.66, -2.02, 0, 'BRANCH', 'Y', 45, 0],
        [-1.66, -2.02, 0, 'NODE', 'Y', 45, 0],
        [-1.60, -3.02, 0, 'BRANCH', 'Y', 45, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0.90, -0.42, 0, 'BRANCH', 'Y', 45, 0],
        [0.90, -0.42, 0, 'NODE', 'Y', 45, 0],
        [1.81, -0.84, 0, 'BRANCH', 'Y', 45, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 'BRANCH', 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0.10, -0.99, 0, 0, 'Y', 45, 0],
        [-0.69, -1.59, 0, 0, 'Y', 45, 0],
        [-0.53, -2.58, 0, 'BRANCH', 'Y', 45, 0],
        [-0.53, -2.58, 0, 'NODE', 'Y', 45, 0],
    ], dtype=object)

    for ind, coord in enumerate(Coords):
        if coord[3] == 'BRANCH':
            if (coord[0:3] == Coords[ind + 1, 0:3]).all():
                np.delete(Coords, ind, 0)

    lines = []

    j = 0
    for i in range(len(Coords)):
        if (Coords[i, 3] == 'BRANCH') or (i == (len(Coords) - 1)):
            lines.append(Coords[j:i+1].tolist())
            j = i+1

    if not lines:
        Lines = [Coords[:]]
    else:
        Lines = [line for line in lines if len(line) > 1]

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    patches = []
    lines = []
    Vs = []
    all_r_lines = []
    texts = []


    for num, line in enumerate(Lines):
        line = np.asarray(line, dtype=object)
        num_coords = line[:, 0:2]
        cumm = 0

        indi_coords = []

        for i, joint in enumerate(line):

            if joint[4] == 'Y' and joint[3] != 'BRANCH':

                """ --------------- BODY -------------------------------- """
                indi_coords.append((joint[0], joint[1]))

                new_coords = ((line[i+1][0]), (line[i+1][1]))
                angle = degrees(atan2(
                    (new_coords[1] - joint[1]),
                    (new_coords[0] - joint[0])
                ))

                if cumm > 0:
                    Lines[num][i][6] = cumm

                cumm += 1

            else:
                indi_coords.append((joint[0], joint[1]))
                cumm = 0

        lines.append(np.asarray(indi_coords))

    linestring = MultiLineString(lines)

    for num, line_coords in reversed(list(enumerate(Lines))):
        for i, joint in reversed(list(enumerate(line_coords))):

            if joint[4] == 'Y' and i < (len(Coords)-1) and joint[3] != 'BRANCH':

                if joint[6] > 0:
                    """ --------------- PATCH -------------------------------- """
                    lineA = LineString([(joint[0], joint[1]),
                                        ((line_coords[i+1][0]), (line_coords[i+1][1]))])
                    left_line = affinity.rotate(
                        lineA, joint[5]/2, (joint[0], joint[1]))
                    rigt_line = affinity.rotate(
                        lineA, -joint[5]/2, (joint[0], joint[1]))

                    try:
                        Vs[-1] = ops.unary_union([MultiLineString(
                            [lineA, left_line, rigt_line])] + all_r_lines[-1])
                    except:
                        Vs.append(MultiLineString([lineA, left_line, rigt_line]))

                    """ --------------- ANGLE LINES -------------------------------- """

                    rotate_angle = line_coords[i-1][5]/2
                    r_lines = [affinity.rotate(
                        Vs[-1],
                        j,
                        (line_coords[i-1][0], line_coords[i-1][1])
                    ) for j in np.linspace(-rotate_angle, rotate_angle, num=3)
                    ]

                    all_r_lines += [r_lines]

                    Vs[-1] = ops.unary_union([Vs[-1]] + r_lines)

                else:
                    """ --------------- PATCH -------------------------------- """
                    lineA = LineString([(joint[0], joint[1]),
                                        ((line_coords[i+1][0]), (line_coords[i+1][1]))])
                    left_line = affinity.rotate(
                        lineA, joint[5]/2, (joint[0], joint[1]))
                    rigt_line = affinity.rotate(
                        lineA, -joint[5]/2, (joint[0], joint[1]))

                    Vs.append(MultiLineString([lineA, left_line, rigt_line]))

                    all_r_lines = []

    all_lines = Vs

    a = ops.unary_union(all_lines)

    creature = (Vs + [a] + [linestring])

    polies = []
    for l in creature:
        polies.append(Polygon(l.buffer(0.5)))

    creature_poly = ops.unary_union(polies)
    creature_patch = PolygonPatch(creature_poly, fc='BLUE', alpha=0.1)

    absorbA = creature_poly
    moves = Vs

    for c_l in linestring:
        x, y = c_l.xy
        ax.plot(x, y)

    for m in all_lines:
        for line in m:
            x, y = line.xy
            ax.plot(x, y, 'g--', alpha=0.25)

    ax.axis('equal')

    ax.add_patch(creature_patch)

    ax.axis('equal')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57753813/speed-up-shapely-buffer

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to CodeReview! I'm not familiar enough with your stack to suggest performance improvements, but one other thing I will suggest: use a fixed-width format for your table, like this:

```
    Coords = np.array([
        [ 0.00,  0.00, 0.00,     0.00,  'N',  0, 0],
        [ 0.00,  1.00, 0.00, 'BRANCH',  'N',  0, 0],
        [ 0.00,  0.00, 0.00, 'BRANCH', 0.00,  0, 0],
        [ 0.00,  0.00, 0.00,     0.00, 0.00,  0, 0],
        [-0.85, -0.51, 0.00, 'BRANCH',  'Y', 45, 0],
        [-0.85, -0.51, 0.00,   'NODE',  'Y', 45, 0],
        [-1.71, -1.03, 0.00,     0.00,  'Y', 45, 0],
        [-1.66, -2.02, 0.00, 'BRANCH',  'Y', 45, 0],
        [-1.66, -2.02, 0.00,   'NODE',  'Y', 45, 0],
        [-1.60, -3.02, 0.00, 'BRANCH',  'Y', 45, 0],
        [ 0.00,  0.00, 0.00,     0.00, 0.00,  0, 0],
        [ 0.90, -0.42, 0.00, 'BRANCH',  'Y', 45, 0],
        [ 0.90, -0.42, 0.00,   'NODE',  'Y', 45, 0],
        [ 1.81, -0.84, 0.00, 'BRANCH',  'Y', 45, 0],
        [ 0.00,  0.00, 0.00, 'BRANCH', 0.00,  0, 0],
        [ 0.00,  0.00, 0.00,     0.00, 0.00,  0, 0],
        [ 0.10, -0.99, 0.00,     0.00,  'Y', 45, 0],
        [-0.69, -1.59, 0.00,     0.00,  'Y', 45, 0],
        [-0.53, -2.58, 0.00, 'BRANCH',  'Y', 45, 0],
        [-0.53, -2.58, 0.00,   'NODE',  'Y', 45, 0],
    ], dtype=object)
```

It's more legible. In this case it actually violates PEP8, but this violation is actually worth it for the increase in legibility.

Otherwise, you really need to make subroutines. If you care enough about performance, subroutines will help you understand the output of a profiler.

Comment: You're right about readability, but I think a better approach would be to move this data to an external text file (maybe CSV to use `numpy.loadtxt`? I don't think JSON would be a good choice here).